# Can I consolidate the results of my Linq to SQL query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

Can I consolidate my Linq to Sql query results as part of the query? For example the following query would return list A below. I want my list to be consolidated like list B below.

```
        IEnumerable<JoinClass> points =
                         from c in db.Users2
                         join e in db.Categories on c.Id_Users2 equals e.FK_Users2
                         join f in db.Programs on e.Id_Category equals f.FK_Categories
                         join g in db.Points on f.Id_Programs equals g.FK_Programs
                         where c.EEID == UserEEIDCast
                         orderby g.EntryDate ascending
                         select new JoinClass
                         {
                             Category = e.Category,
                             Programs = f.Programs,
                             Points = g.Points,
                             EEID = c.EEID,
                             EntryDate = g.EntryDate,
                             Name = c.Name



        return View(points);
```

**List A**

Name Program Points

---

Jim Running 10

Jim Running 3

Jim Walking 7

Jim Walking 4

Bob Running 2
Bob Running 1

**List B**

Name Program Points

---

Jim Running 13

Jim Walking 11

Bob Running 3

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
points = points
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Program } )
    .Select(x => new JoinClass() {Name = x.Key.Name, Program = x.Key.Program, Points = x.Sum(y => y.Points) /* copy other properties to the new JoinClass here */ });
```

This code groups the result using a composite key (Name and Program), then for each group it creates a new JoinClass with Points equal to the sum of all the points in that group.